# how to calculate a test for one sample in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in which I would like to calculate Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on each column separately.

Let's say my matrix is like below

```
    Name    A    Name        B       Name       C         Name       D
1007_s  -0.2815  1007_s_  -0.2032   1007_s_at  -0.2539  1007_s_at   0.0410
1053_at -0.0113  1053_at   0.0285   1053_at    -0.0675  1053_at     0.0048
117_at  -0.0448  117_at   -0.1360   117_at     -0.2189  117_at      0.0637
121_at  -0.0810  121_at    0.1412   121_at      0.0464  121_at      -0.0180
1255_g  0.0486   1255_g   -0.0239   1255_g_at   0.0753  1255_g_at   -0.0670
1294_at -0.1090  1294_at  -0.1266   1294_at    -0.3023  1294_at     0.0101
1316_at -0.0389  1316_at   0.0915   1316_at    -0.1352  1316_at     0.1189
1320_at 0.0147   1320_at  -0.0064   1320_at     0.0090  1320_at    -0.0411
1405_i_ 0.0000   1405_i_   0.2178   1405_i_at   -0.3024 1405_i_at   0.2265
1431_at 0.0318   1431_a    0.0556   1431_at     -0.0434 1431_at     -0.0180
```

Comment: use `dput(yourdata)` (except with whatever your variable is called in the argument) to get some code that will let us *reproduce* what you have there.

Comment: @Glen_b done, please check above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the statistic and p-value:

```
  f <- function(x) unlist(ks.test(x,"punif")[1:2])
  apply(x[,seq(1,7,by=2)],2,f)
```

Here's the output:

```
                       A           B            C            D
statistic.D 9.514000e-01 7.82200e-01 9.247000e-01 7.811000e-01
p.value     1.471046e-13 5.48744e-07 1.172162e-11 1.003735e-05
Warning message:
In ks.test(x, "punif") :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
```

Replace `"punif"` with whatever cdf you need (e.g. `"pnorm"` for standard normal).

If you need the whole of the test in a list, just omit the `[1:2]` and the `unlist`.

Comment: I need the distance as well. can you also please comment on what if I have the second type of data as described above ?

Comment: not exactly. I have another data type which one column is name and one column is value alternatively. I want to perform KS on each value column and save the results in a file showing D,value for each column

Comment: thank you so much, I have one small question related to this, actually, this helps when you know the dimension of your data where you mentioned seq(1,7,by=2). However, my real data is very large (1.5 Gb and it is saved as values not data) how can I set this ? i have tried seq(1,length(my data),by=2) I got a message like "incorrect number of dimensions"